# Will Ubuntu run on this old pc?

Tags: graphics

```
s3unichrome 3D gpu
256mb of ram can upgrade to 512mb
AMD sempron 3100+ @ 1.8ghz 
100gb hhd 
emachine  t3104
```

The computer runs Windows XP but slowly and it crashes. It is about 13 years old and has the original Windows install.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: Ubuntu, probably not, unless you got an older kernel. There are many other options though for linux. Im sure tiny core would run great, you could go to distrowatch.com and look for linux version for older PCs.

Answer (score 1):

256MB RAM  is a very little amount of RAM in these days. It's hardly enough to run any kind of modern GUI. [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)  is probably the most lightweight distro of Ubuntu, using the LXDE desktop environment. If you're open to try another distro, there's always [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm), which needs very little resources

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is very little memory in this day and age. So you may have trouble with Ubuntu. Try the lighter ones and see how you get on.

If you are keen to stay with Ubuntu though upgrade to the 512 and try running the live version from USB or cd. This will give you a good indication of how it will run and toy can go from there.